# How to test if a component is rendered or not by jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to learn tdd in react. I have a parent component which gets props from app component and based on the props render either child1 component or child2 component. Here are my react files:

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Parent from './Parent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent number={"one"} word={"hello"}/>
      {/* can be one or two */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Parent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Child1 from './Child1';
import Child2 from './Child2';

function Parent({number,word}) {
  return (
    <div className="Parent" data-testid="parent-test">
      {number === 'one' &&
        <Child1 />
      }
      {number === 'two' &&
        <Child2/>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

child1.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Child1() {
  return (
    <div>
      I am Child1
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child1;
```

child2.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Child2() {
  return (
    <div>
      I am Child2
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child2;
`

How can I write a test using Jest and enzyme to check in parent file based on props if child1 is rendered or not.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### **You shouldn't check if your child component is rendered or not, but check for the actual rendered content (which the testing library encourage you to do)**

For testing it in react-testing-library you could do something like this:

```
test("If Child1 is rendered!", () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<Parent number="one" word="hello" />);
  expect(getByText("I am Child1")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: I see your point thanks for that! cheers :)

Comment: This is not always desirable. Imagine you are rendering a link. Testing for the rendered text of the link, does not test if it is indeed a link.